# Passing more than two sys.argv in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, visa

I have a small question in passing two or more sys.argv arguments in Python. I do it using following code.

```
from visa import *
import sys
inst = instrument(sys.argv[1])
inst.write("*rst; status:preset; *cls")
inst.write("voltage:UNIT Vrms")
inst.write("apply:SIN %s %s" % sys.argv[2] % sys.argv[3])
```

But this code does not generate any answer.

But if I pass the same code with values embedded using the code

```
from visa import *
import sys
inst = instrument("USB0::0x164E::0x13EC::TW00008555")
inst.write("*rst; status:preset; *cls")
inst.write("voltage:UNIT Vrms")
inst.write("apply:SIN 1000, 0.5")
```

I get the result.

Is there something I am missing? Any help would be very useful to pass more than two `sys.argv`'s in Python.

Comment: in the second snippet there is additional comma `,` in the last line?

Comment: please provide the content of `sys.argv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the string formatting is not good, you should try:

```
inst.write("apply:SIN %s %s" % (sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]))
```

also in the second snippet there is an additional comma so maybe:

```
inst.write("apply:SIN %s, %s" % (sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]))
```

Comment: sorry mate they both did not work, i did not get anything. Is there anything else i could do any help would be really helpful. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: you can try to insert `print sys.argv` at the beginning to ensure you pass arguments correctly.

Comment: thanks you very much mate, the second one is working fine. While trying for the first time i left a bracket. it's working mate.

Comment: As I state in my answer, this method of string formatting is outdated, and superseded by `str.format()`. It's bad practice to continue to use it.

Comment: @Lattyware I will try using format() as well! But thanks I learned something new today.

Answer (score 4):

You want to pass a tuple into the string formatting:

```
>>> "test %s %s" % ("a", "b")
'test a b'
```

The way you are currently doing it doesn't work, as what you are telling it to do is do the formatting operation twice, inserting the third argument into the second one.

Do note that in new code, [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is the preferred method of string formatting:

```
>>> "test {0} {1}".format("a", "b")
'test a b'
```

So you would use, for example:

```
inst.write("apply:SIN {0}, {1}".format(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]))
```

This exists in Python 2.6 and above, and should be used there over the modulo operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying mate. So what could be done to format them correctly? Any help?

Comment: @Kishorepandey My answer explains that. What issue do you have with it?